# Is there any way to make a Javascript to be aware of new dynamic vars?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have something like the following:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In `scripts.js` I have the following code:

```
var gridId = window['someGridId'];
```

The problem is `someGridId` is generated on the backend through an AJAX call and it's append to the DOM using `.html()`. That way `scripts.js` doesn't know about the existence of the var and therefore the code is not executed.

Is there any way to let the script know about the new var existence?

Comment: Why would you insert something into the DOM that has nothing to do with the DOM?  Just use your data directly after you get the response data with your AJAX  call.

Comment: @Brad what's inside `scripts.js` is a code common to several place, I do not want to repeat myself writing such code inside the `success()` for the AJAX call if that is what you mean

Comment: Your question makes zero sense.  Why would you have to repeat anything?

Comment: _"The problem is `someGridId` is generated on the backend through an AJAX call and it's append to the DOM using `.html()`"_ ? Question is not clear. Can you create a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net or plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate issue?

Comment: The code in `scripts.js` needs to wait until the function is called before trying to access `window.someGridId`. That way, it will work if the variable is added later.

Comment: @Barmar that's is exactly what I am trying to do. Do you mean something like wrap everything under `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: That won't do it, the `DOMReady` event doesn't wait for AJAX calls to complete.

Comment: @guest271314 it's hard to me to replicate this, is not a simple use case and has a lot of backend dependencies I don't have a clue about replicate this on jsFiddle, sorry

Comment: @Barmar then how? Could you answer this with some examples?

Comment: It seems like you have a fundamental design problem. General-purpose libraries shouldn't depend on global variables that are set in the calling code.

Comment: Then how do you expect an accurate Answer to be provided?

Comment: @Barmar I can not say the opposite, it's a bad design but this is legacy code and I can't change it right now again I am sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redesign `scripts.js` so it doesn't require the global variable to be set at the time it's loaded. Functions that use `gridId` will need to set it when they're called. E.g. instead of:

```
gridId = window['someGridId'];
function foo() {
    // code that uses gridId
}
```

it should be:

```
function foo() {
    var gridId = window['someGridId'];
    // code that uses gridId
}
```

Another possibility is to provide an initialization function that sets the global variables:

```
function initVars() {
    gridId = window['someGridId'];
    ...
}
```

All the web pages that use `scripts.js` would then have to call `initVars()` after they've loaded everything that it depends on. Pages that don't load these items dynamically can just do:

```
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</script>initVars();</script>
```

Your page can call `initVars()` in the callback function of the AJAX call that adds the DOM elements.